# ¿Cómo mostrar el valor de un vector de forma ordenada de acuerdo a una consigna en C?

Tags: array, c

tengo un problema y no encuentro solución. Debo hacer un código en C donde el usuario permita y guarde valores enteros no nulos ni negativos en un vector, y si éste ingresa numeros no positivos o nulos, debe mostrar el vector en forma ordenada. El problema es que no me imprime el vector en cuestión sino el último valor ingresado:

```
void vector(){
    int i;
    int n[1]={};

    do{
        for(i=0;i>0;i++);

        printf("Introduzca un numero entero positivo: ");
        scanf("%d", &n[i]);

        if(n[i]<=0) {
            puts("El numero es negativo o nulo.");
        }
    } while(n[i]>0);

    for(i=0;i>0;i++);{
        int num;
        num = n[i];
        printf("%d ", num);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector();
    return 0;
}
```

Adjunto imagen de consola:

[image: Imagen de consola del código en cuestión.]

Comment: Primero, tienes un arreglo con espacio para un solo elemento. Segundo, no uses un for si quieres acceder a un único elemento. Como siempre se trata del elemento en la posición 0 podrías dejar de usar la variable `i` incluso. Si estás aprendiendo a programar, sugiero que uses un lenguaje de alto nivel o con una mejor curva de aprendizaje, como Python o incluso en pseudo código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Primer problema**: el array solo admite un número:

```
int n[1]={};
```

Aquí sucede que nadie va a comprobar si escribes fuera de los límites del array, es decir, si tu a continuación escribes

```
n[1000]=3;
```

pues al compilador como que le va a parecer bien. El problema es que esa posición 1000 no está reservada para el array, sino que ese puede ser el espacio de memoria de otra variable a la que le estás sobreescribiendo su valor. Esto suele provocar comportamientos erráticos en el programa.

Dado que no sabes cuántos números va a introducir el usuario, aquí tienes dos posibilidades:

1. Creas un array lo suficientemente grande como para asegurarte de que no "*te sales*".

   ```
   int n[1000];
   ```

   Pero claro, llegados a este punto debes que tener en cuenta que los arrays lo estás creando en la pila del programa, una región de memoria con un tamaño de unos pocos Kb ... si te excedes en capacidad el programa simplemente morirá.

   Para evitar sustos lo mejor es usar memoria dinámica

   ```
   int * n = (int*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));

   // ...

   free(n);
   ```
2. Vas reservando memoria sobre la marcha, es decir, ir incrementando el tamaño de la reserva de memoria según vayamos añadiendo elementos.

   Para aplicar esta solución debes tener en cuenta que estás usando exclusivamente memoria dinámica. Pedir memoria dinámica es un proceso lento, por lo que no conviene incrementar la memoria a cada valor introducido. Es preferible hacer reservas cada x elementos (por ejemplo 10 o 100). Para poder hacerlo así necesitamos llevar la cuenta del número de elementos que hemos añadido al array

   ```
   #define CHUNK_SIZE 10
   int * n = NULL;

   for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
   {
       if (i%CHUNK_SIZE == 0)
       {
           n = realloc(n, (i+CHUNK_SIZE) * sizeof(int));
           if (n == NULL)
           {
               // te has quedado sin memoria ... ERROR!!!
               exit(100);
           }
       }

       n[i] = i;
   }

   // ...

   free(n);
   ```

**Segundo problema**: no estás imprimiendo correctamente el array

```
for(i=0;i>0;i++);{
    int num;
    num = n[i];
    printf("%d ", num);
}
```

Este bucle no se va a ejecutar nunca. Es literalmente imposible que 0>0, luego la condición inicial no va a cumplir la condición y el bucle, simplemente, no se ejecutará.

**Tercer problema**: El bucle anterior **no hace nada**

Fíjate en el punto y coma que está tras el bucle `for`

```
for(i=0;i>0;i++);{
//              ^ AQUI
```

**Cuarto problema**: No puedes tocar `i`

Seguimos con el mismo bucle. En el mismo, **no puedes modificar** la variable `i`. Esta variable es la única que lleva la cuenta del número de elementos en el array. Si la modificas perderás ese valor y ya no sabrás cuando debes parar.

Debes utilizar otra variable para iterar, y el rango de iteración debe ser `(0, i)`

Corrigiendo estos tres errores a la vez, el bucle quedaría así:

```
for(int j=0;j<=i; j++){
    printf("%d ", n[j]);
}
```